# What might lead to a sudden increase in ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait time?

Tags: sql-server, performance, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, async-network-io

At approximately 2021-06-14 02:00 (UTC) my website began performing very poorly (some requests taking >10s). An analysis of the logs shows that the slowdown only affects routes which establish a DB connection. When I look at the DB, I can see that I am experiencing high Network I/O (ASYNC_NETWORK_IO) wait times.

My understanding is that this can point to a couple problems. Either there is an issue with the network, or more likely, a problem with the application consuming the DB results.
https://www.sqlshack.com/reducing-sql-server-async_network_io-wait-type/

Unfortunately, when I investigate any further, both the network and the client seem to be fine.

###### Problem with the network?

- ping < 1ms
- Utilizing a small fraction of 10GbE bandwidth
- Auto-Negotiation is detecting the network bandwidth properly

###### Web server / Application processing results too slowly?

- CPU usage is fine
- No code changes when slowdown began
- Request queue emptied quickly

Is there any other explanation for why I might see a sudden increase in ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait time?

###### *Update*

Most resources (like the one I linked above) say that a problem with SQL Server itself is unlikely. However, when I switched out my application's connection string to use my test db (located on a different server), the site performance went back to normal, and no ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait times could be seen in my test db.

If the issue was with the web server or the client application, I would have expected to see the connection to the test db cause high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait times there as well.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this from the SQL Server side?

Comment: What do you call high, and how do you know there are no other waits? 10Gb bandwidth between where and where, is that all the way to the web server?

Comment: @Charlieface, wait times of ~2000ms for every second meaning there are about 2 tasks waiting at any given moment. I know there are no other waits by looking at the Activity Monitor in SSMS.